# use custom css by wordpress subfolder?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the polylang plugin. Additional css is required for the arabic language. How can I run css according to the subfolder in the functions?
example:

```
//This is your own css file
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/yellow.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
//this is the code that will also work according to subfolders
<?php if( url(www.example.com/ar) ) ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/blue.css" type="text/css" media="screen"  />
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to fetch styles for a page in php.
Try this

```
<!--Styles included -->
<style>
<?php include '/blue.css'?>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_style('theme', PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/css/test.css');
```

Another

```
 function load_admin_script() { 
      wp_enqueue_style('theme', DSSLIDER_PATH . 'assets/css/test.css'); 
}  
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_script' );
```